# PHP Single array to multidimensional with same key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a simple php function to transform a simple array to multidimensional one with same key ?

For now I use :

```
 $array = [1, 4, 6];
 $arrayMulti = [];

 foreach ($array as $row) {
      $arrayMulti []= [
        'foreign_id' => $row,
      ];
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that using array_map

```
$array = [1, 4, 6]; 
$array = array_map(function ($a) { return array('foriegn_id'=>$a); }, $array);
print_r($array);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [foriegn_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [foriegn_id] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [foriegn_id] => 6
        )

)
```

Comment: Yes one line is better, I thought a function existed like array_transform ) thanks